# how to access a ModelAndView object within the jsp page

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a code like this in my controller.

```
ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView("person/sometrends");  
result.addObject("data", data);  // data -> Map
```

In my JSP page I have written some Java code that is dependent on the data object.
How can I get that data object within the JSP code?

I tried something like this (pseudo code).

```
<%
    Map x = ${data};
%>
```

But that doesn't work. Not sure how to access it.

Answer (score 36):

In a scriptlet, you use the request object like so:

`<% Map myMap = (Map) request.getAttribute("data"); %>`

If you want to use something like JSTL instead of a scriptlet, you could do:

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${data}">
Name:  ${entry.key} <br/>
Value: ${entry.value} <br/>
</c:forEach>
```

As Davemeister and novice pointed out, combining EL inside a scriptlet was the root cause of your error.

Comment: how can we get a `jsp` variable (i.e. a textarea input) in a `class` (i.e. spring controller) with a function which return a ModelAndView object?

Answer (score 12):

Let me more specific, if you want to use `jsp` instead of `jstl` to access the `Model` you would do something like this:

```
<% Map x = (Map)request.getAttribute("data") %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
request.getAttribute("data")
```

Answer (score 2):

try`<% String username = (String)request.getAttribute("data"); %>`

Answer (score 1):

Using expression language inside the scriptlet would be the cause.

Answer (score -2):

include: `<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>`

and then...

```
<%
    Map x = ${data};
%>
```